# How to Use Static variable in project level ina java?

Tags: java, static

I have a doubt on using of Static variable on project level.

Actually I have a `Static` variable in a class  in one project folder. 
I need to use that Static variable to another project folder.

How I can get that static variable?

Comment: well a `public static` variable will be visible between packages (project folders), however you might want to read about encapsulation.

Comment: You can reference that project and and access that 'public static' variable.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have `variable`

```
public class Test {
                 public static final String TEST="test";  
}
```

in `project A.`

Create a JAR file and put in Project's B buildpath.

In project B ..

```
public class TestB {

             public static void main(String args[]){

             System.out.println(Test.TEST);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need it to be static? An option is to do like this:

```
public class TestClass{
    private int myVariable;

    public int getValue(){
        return myVariable;
    }

    public void setValue(int newValue){
        myVariable = newValue;
    }
}
```

This way you can access it with the `getValue()` method, but it doesn't have to be `static`. This is an example of [encapsulation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm). If you don't already know about encapsulation, you should spend some time looking into it, as you will definitely need it in your programming career!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse you can link projects together so that you can you source code from one project in another.

Here's a couple of screenshots to get you going:

Files in use
[image: Files in use]

Project setup for Project_B (under Order and export you can select to include this project when building the jar-file for Project_B)
[image: Project setup for Project_B (under Order and export you can select to include this project when building the jar-file for Project_B)]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `static import` to have that package and class and all static variables imported into the class you want to use it,then you will use it as though it was declared in your class.or

You can just import the package and access the static variable by invoking it using the class name say like `ClassName.staticVariable` an maybe assign it to a variable in your class if you gonna use it more often than once.

These are just suggestions.